# SSIS Force all fields to be maximum column length

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an existing SSIS package that contains several data types. We are consuming 8 flat files (CSV's) and pushing them to a SQL Server Database. There are several fields that could, possibly, be unreasonable in length. The preferred method would be a global setting to trim a string if it's longer than it's destination allows.

Is there any feature for this, or does it have to be handled on a column by column approach using derived columns for each?

Comment: Ignore failure on truncation perhaps? Not exactly graceful, but a three click option instead of deriving the columns.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I actually have that set, but then it doesn't insert any rows to the database (just skips the whole import for that particular file)

Comment: Are you using text/ntext?

Comment: DB: varchar, SSIS imports as DW_STR